# Unable to find system thread 1C10

Tags: windows, electron, crash-reports

I am developing an Electron app for Windows and within the past couple weeks the app has begun to crash intermittently without any apparent cause. I downloaded the windows debugging tools to examine the crash dumps and found the error `Unable to find system thread 1C10`. What does this error mean? How can I proceed?